# iPad App - Prevent it from being installed on an iPad 1

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

I have an app which is fairly memory intensive. Although the app does fine on iPad 2 and above it fails miserably on an iPad 1. 
Is there any way that I can prevent an app from installing on an iPad 1.

Answer (score 3):

you can make your app only 6.0 and above, ipad 1s can't upgrade to 6.0

Comment: or you can put UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in info.plist and find out which device capabilities is only supported by iPad 2 or greater.

Comment: If the capability is not used by the app (say you require a camera, for example), Apple might reject it. They don't allow you to use capabilities to discriminate devices, only to ensure the app works as expected.

Comment: What are the chances of rejection ? Any other capabilities other than camera ?